# Buttons lost onClickListener when LinearLayout was moved to another place

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So, I'm making an App in Android Studio, following some orders of a form. There's a part where I have to develop a dynamic UI, so I have to change de app in a way to create a flexible landscape layout.
The normal application in landscape mode has 2 main LinearLayout in vertical, with weight 0.5 each.

Basicly, the goal is to check if the left LinearLayout "father" has sufficient height in landscape mode, to have the 3 LinearLayout "child's" inside. If not, I have to pass the last LinearLayout child to the other half LinearLayout "father".

I developed this code to do so:

```
val topLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.layoutTop)
val heightNeeded :Int = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linearLayoutRed).height * 3
if ( topLayout.height < heightNeeded ) {

    val blueLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linearLayoutBlue)

    val secondHalf = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linearLayoutSecondHalf)
    val totalValueL = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linearLayoutResultingColor)

    topLayout.removeView(blueLayout)
    if (blueLayout.parent != null) {
        (blueLayout.parent as ViewGroup).removeView(blueLayout)
    }

    secondHalf.removeView(totalValueL)
    if (totalValueL.parent != null) {
        (totalValueL.parent as ViewGroup).removeView(totalValueL)
    }

    val paddTop = blueLayout.paddingTop
    blueLayout.setPaddingRelative(0,paddTop,0,0)

    secondHalf.addView(blueLayout)
    secondHalf.addView(totalValueL)
```

It worked and did the result I wanted, but everything that was inside the LinearLayout that I moved to the other LinearLayout lost the activity on them. For example, inside I had 2 buttons that were calling a function, and now I can't click on them, it doesnt recognize them.

Could you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your XML layout code?

Comment: It is  a bit too extense, how do you want me to send it?

Comment: Just edit your question, adding it at the bottom.

Comment: Nevermind, found it, it wasn't my error, was the way I was calling it. Thanks anyway